# How to hide default folders in Windows?

Tags: windows, git, shell, cmd, terminal

I haven't used Windows in years and trying to simply run the command: "**ls**" to show the list of files/folders, but when I do that I see other default folders that I don't want to show. Can anyone tell me how to only show "**MyFolder**" when doing "ls"? Thanks a lot in advance.

NOTES:

**1)** I'm currently using Windows 11

**2)** I also tried using **git bash** and the result is the same.

This is what I see when doing "ls" on the CMD.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
attrib +h [FolderName/FileName]
```

To hide your folder. You can also follow this link to learn more [How to hide/unhide the folders/files using command prompt in windows](https://www.minitool.com/news/how-to-hide-a-folder-in-windows-10.html)